# SOLR query to check if a field is set

Tags: apache, search, solr, lucene, solr4

so I added a new field called 'theField' to my documents. Some of them managed to have the fields set correctly others don't

How do I go about making a SOLR query to only select documents whose 'theField' field is set properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Range Query with both ends open. like:

```
theField:[* TO *]
```